# Executing SQL Server 2014 Configuration Manager

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

What It basically says is that this application was blocked for my own protection. It also says that An administrator refused the execution of this application and I should contact him (the administrator).

I'm using Windows 10. I only have one account and I'm an administrator. I can't login into SQL because I need to run the service first.

I tried multiple methods to get access to this including: **Services** from Task manager, **Computer Management** , typing **SQLServerManager12.msc** everything resulted to the same thing. except the Services thing, when I start the SQL service, It doesn't want to.

Comment: Did try with `This PC -> Management -> Services?`

Comment: @Sami I can access Services from Task Manager as I said, but when I try to run, It does want to.

Comment: Did you check the type of your account? and in which group ?